# How to optimize/cache Rails query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, caching

I've Rails application where query takes way too long time. It uses postgresql DB and query consists of **one** table with thousands of records.

**statistics_controller.rb**

```
all_data = Usagedata.select([:start_time, :end_time, :node_count, :processors, :id, :wall_duration, :local_user_id]) 
    .where(Usagedata.arel_table[(:wall_duration)].not_eq("0"))
    .in_range( @from_date, @to_date)
if @user
  all_data = all_data.by_user(@user)
end

all_data = all_data.to_a #Forcing to make query 
@data = all_data = all_data.to_a
```

What I'd like to do is to keep **main** query result (without in_range and user statement) in Rails serverside application cache and update data once per hour.

**Part of the code which should be cached**:

```
Usagedata.select([:start_time, :end_time, :node_count, :processors, :id, :wall_duration, :local_user_id]) 
    .where(Usagedata.arel_table[(:wall_duration)].not_eq("0"))
```

**Usage of cached records**

Addition to that client can select date ranges from calendar @from_date and @to_date. Time period between dates can be from 1 day...~3 years. (This is why cache should store all records from DB table.) Data is used to draw charts and show/calculate top users statistics.

I've tried @MrTheWalrus solution

```
@statistics = Rails.cache.fetch('usagedata', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  Usagedata.select([:start_time, :end_time, :node_count, :processors, :id, :wall_duration, :local_user_id])
    .where(Usagedata.arel_table[(:wall_duration)].not_eq("0")).all
end
```

But this way I can't get my subquery to work:

```
all_data = @statistics.in_range( @from_date, @to_date)
if @user
  all_data = all_data.by_user(@user)
end
```

This gives me an error:

```
undefined method `in_range' for #<Array:0x007fa5ecc77588>
```

Although I have in_range defined in Usagedata model like this:

```
def self.in_range(from_date, to_date)
  where("start_time <= :to AND end_time >= :from", :from => from_date, :to => to_date)
end
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

**EDIT: Thanks to @Craig Ringer solution I've managed to solve the indexes issue described here:**

The whole application seems to be really slow. What am I doing wrong? Probably I need to add indexes as well but how?

```
  Usagedata Load (243.4ms)  SELECT start_time, end_time, node_count, processors, id, wall_duration, local_user_id FROM "usagedata" WHERE ("usagedata"."wall_duration" != 0) AND (start_time <= '2013-09-02 20:59:59.999999' AND end_time >= '2013-05-05 21:00:00.000000')EXPLAIN (1.9ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT start_time, end_time, node_count, processors, id, wall_duration, local_user_id FROM "usagedata" WHERE ("usagedata"."wall_duration" != 0) AND (start_time <= '2013-09-02 20:59:59.999999' AND end_time >= '2013-05-05 21:00:00.000000')

EXPLAIN for: SELECT start_time, end_time, node_count, processors, id, wall_duration, local_user_id FROM "usagedata"  WHERE ("usagedata"."wall_duration" != 0) AND (start_time <= '2013-09-02 20:59:59.999999' AND end_time >= '2013-05-05 21:00:00.000000')
QUERY PLAN
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on usagedata  (cost=0.00..4558.02 rows=7989 width=34)
 Filter: ((wall_duration <> 0) AND (start_time <= '2013-09-02 20:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_time >= '2013-05-05 21:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
 (2 rows)
```

Comment: An partial index on `start_time, end_time` with a `WHERE ("usagedata"."wall_duration" != 0)` index filter clause will make this query a *lot* quicker. Or even a non-partial index on `(start_time, end_time)`. As for the cache: the database side version of this is called a "materialized view" so search for "rails materialized view" and see if you find anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indexing drained query time to Usagedata Load (143.0ms)! It's almost twice as fast now. :) Going to learn about materialized view now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig Ringer's comment already discussed indexing, so I'm just going to talk about caching.

The problem with the caching code you include is that the thing you're caching is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` - basically just a SQL query waiting to run, not the results of that query. Caching the relation means that each time it's loaded from the cache, it still has to execute the query, which is the part that takes a long time. Tack an `.all` on to the end to force the query to actually run - that will make sure that the results are cached, not the query:

```
@statistics = Rails.cache.fetch('usagedata', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  Usagedata.select([:start_time, :end_time, :node_count, :processors, :id, :wall_duration, :local_user_id]).
    where(Usagedata.arel_table[(:wall_duration)].not_eq("0")).all
end
```

**Edit:**
The reason you can't call `.in_range` on this is that `.in_range` modifies the query (by adding a `WHERE` clause). Once you've run the query and cached the results, you can't modify it in that way - the whole point of caching query results is that you run the query once and use the results multiple times - if the query changes, that's not an option.

Assuming that adding indexing hasn't solved your problem already, my suggestion is that you filter the results in Ruby, rather than in the database. Assuming you've already populated the cache (via Whenever or in some other manner):

```
from_time = 1.week.ago
to_time = 1.day.ago
@statistics = Rails.cache.fetch('usagedata')
@filtered_statistics = @statistics.select do |item|
  item.start_time < to_time && item.end_time > from_time
end
```

Comment: Just found out that this solution doesn't work for me, I need more serverside solution. Some scheduled tasks which will update data in rails app cache every hour. This solution updates cache on first time when client opens the page but query update can take more than a minute so on first time nobody wants to wait that long.

Comment: @Raccoon Check out the Whenever gem (https://github.com/javan/whenever) - it should make it pretty easy to schedule a cache update every hour.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for but I'm having problem implementing it. I updated my question and really hope that you can help my bit further. I can't even get your previous solution to work, although without caching everything is working perfectly.  :(

Answer (score 1):

An partial index on (`start_time`, `end_time`) with a `WHERE ("usagedata"."wall_duration" != 0)` index filter clause will make this query a lot quicker. Or even a non-partial index on `(start_time, end_time)`.

This may render client-side caching unnecessary. If not, look into whether Rails has any support for creating and managing server-side materialized views.

Comment: What kind of method should I use? Choices are btree, hash, gist, and gin.